# Play 2.5.x - No EntityManager bound to this thread

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, akka

I am migrating from Play 2.3.x to 2.5.x and I have an issue on accessing the DB from an akka actor. I inject a Scheduler as EagerSingleton during the start of the application and from the there I create the schedule to access the DB.

The Actor receives in the constructor the JPAAPI to access the DB but every time that it tries to access the DB I receive the error below.

Has anyone a fix for the issue?

Should I also inject the HTTP Context? How can I do that?

> 2017-03-23 11:46:16.990 +0000 - DashboardMonitor.onReceive:73 - check status
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: JPA transaction failed
>
> at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:198)
>     at actors.DashboardMonitor.onReceive(DashboardMonitor.java:77)
>     at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
>     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:484)
>     at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
>     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
>     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPAApi.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on this thread.
>
> at play.db.jpa.JPAEntityManagerContext.em(JPAEntityManagerContext.java:36)
>     at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:75)
>     at models.Probe.getAllProbes(Probe.java:270)
>     at utils.Utils.updatePlatformStatus(Utils.java:524)
>     at actors.DashboardMonitor.lambda$onReceive$0(DashboardMonitor.java:78)
>     at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$2(DefaultJPAApi.java:194)
>     at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$3(DefaultJPAApi.java:211)
>     at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:152)
>     at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:210)
>     at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:193)
>   ... 13 more

This is the code I use:

```
@Singleton
public class DashboardMonitor extends UntypedActor {


    private final JPAApi jpaApi;

    @Inject
    public DashboardMonitor(JPAApi jpaApi) {

        this.jpaApi = jpaApi;

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

        // check message type
        if (message.equals("updateStatus")) {

            try {

                jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
                    Utils.updatePlatformStatus();
                });


            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Scheduler:

```
@Singleton
public class DashboardScheduler {

    // Start aggregate session for aggregate probe
    private Cancellable updateStatusSchedule = null;

    @Inject
    public DashboardScheduler(ApplicationLifecycle lifeCycle, ActorSystem system, @Named("dashboard-monitor") ActorRef dashboardActor) {

        startUpdateStatus(system, dashboardActor);
        initStopHook(lifeCycle);

    }

    /**
     * Start probesTimedOutScheduler
     */
    private void startUpdateStatus(ActorSystem system, ActorRef dashboardActor) {

        if (updateStatusSchedule == null || updateStatusSchedule.isCancelled()) {

            updateStatusSchedule = system.scheduler().schedule(
                    Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    Duration.create((GlobalConfiguration.probeUpdateInterval), TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    dashboardActor,
                    "updateStatus",
                    system.dispatcher(),
                    null);

        }

    }

}
```

Injection Module:

```
public class GlobalBootstrapModule extends AbstractModule implements    AkkaGuiceSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        bindActor(DashboardMonitor.class, "dashboard-monitor");
        bind(DashboardScheduler.class).asEagerSingleton();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128211/how-can-use-jpa-with-play-2-5-without-creating-a-entitymanager-factory-for-each)? It looks like you do not have a Entity manager injected on you application.